# no extra row after enter in textarea

Tags: javascript

I have a text-area with no text inside, if i hit enter the cursor move's to the second row and blinking.
I put some code inside to stop it but still nothing the text-area moves down. example:

```
    function areaOnkeydown(e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code === 13) {
            if (_text.value === '') {
                return;   // if there's no text and hit enter.. // return but move to second row
            } else {
            // do something here..
            }
        }
    }
```

With 2 words on enter if text-area doesn't have any text remain as is do nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is a little difficult to read, are you saying that you want to disable the "enter" key when the textarea has a value?

Comment: `if (_text.value === '')` will always be false because your first condition has `&& _text.value !== ""`

Comment: I don't want to disable the enter when the area have value, i just want when i hit enter in a blank text-area to remain as is else if the area have text put it inside. In a text-area when you hit enter in with blank text moves to the second row etc depends how many rows you have define, i want to stay in the first row when i hit enter and the text-area doesn't have any value - text inside else if have some text  put it in the text-area.

Answer (score 1):

Just cancel the event when the value is empty. This is done using `Event.preventDefault()` function.

```js
function areaOnkeydown(e) {
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  var value = e.target.value
  if (code === 13) {
    if (value === '') {
      e.preventDefault()
      return;
    } else {
      // update: added this else 28/11/2022
      // so something
    }
    
  }
}

textarea.addEventListener("keydown", areaOnkeydown)
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" rows="4"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I try it in the snippet and make sense but after the first enter the next enter gives
"
next line
"
and still the enter works even in empty line..

Comment: i cant reproduce. for me the enter is totally disabled when value empty

Comment: I understand but i need it..  When press first time enter without text works perfect. If you write something and hit enter the cursor moves to the next row and so on. I send the text from this text-area somewhere else. The only solution i see is that the cursor must return in the first line start after the enter. I try it and with only one row but i think that default is 2 rows. I use text area and not input cause i need the word wrapping and the multi-line if the text is too long.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I post the here the solution that works for me. No more new empty line on enter after text in text-area.

```
function areaOnkeydown(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    var value = e.target.value;
    if (code === 13) {
        if (value === '') {
            if (value && value.indexOf('\n') > -1) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
        onSendText(e);  // also i put the e.preventDefault(); here
    }
}
```

Thanks all for the help!

Comment: great. try shortening your code because you have unnecessary condition and repetition  of code there.